# Foreach loop takes a very long time to break out of

Tags: c#, foreach, watin, enumeration

Scraping a webpage, containing about 250 table divisions.
Using WatiN and WatinCSSSelectors

First I select all td tags with attribute 'width=90%':

```
var allMainTDs = browser.CssSelectAll("td[width=\"90%\"]");
```

Then I make a foreach loop, stick the contents of the var into a List. The int is there to check what td tag the loop is currently at.

```
List<Element> eletd = new List<Element>();
int i = 0;
foreach (Element td in allMainTDs)
{
    eletd.Add(td);
    i++;
    Console.WriteLine(i);                    
}
```

It reaches the 250th tag fairly quickly. But then it takes about 6 minutes (timed with a StopWatch object) to go onto the next statement. What is happening here?

Comment: @MHTn what is the `next statement`

Comment: It doesn't matter, at the moment I have `int i = 0;` and just put a breakpoint there. The issue is that it takes AGES to get to the next line of code after the foreach loop, in this case `int i =0;`.

Comment: It's most likely the Dispose method of the enumerator of the collection returned by CssSelectAll that hogs your time. Can you run this under a profiler?

Comment: Have you tried breaking when you hit that delay, to see where you are in the stack?  It sounds like something is holding up the enumeration of the 250th element.

Comment: @Martinho Fernandes - I just downloaded the ANTS profiler trial but I'm not sure what to be looking at. Currently the foreach loop takes about 84% of the total time cost. However. I have discovered that calls to Watin methods as part of the CSSSelector appear to be the lion's share of this time consuming process... maybe I'll stick to good old looping and if statements...
@Justin Morgan - I've hit pause, and it just highlights in green the foreach loop (specifically the 'in' word). Not sure what that signifies.

Comment: If you want an alternative, you can use the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and [Fizzler](http://code.google.com/p/fizzler/). It's a couple more dependencies, but it might be worth 6 minutes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `foreach` loop is roughly equivalent to the following code (not exactly, but close enough):

```
IEnumerator<T> enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();
try
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
    {
        T element = enumerator.Current;
        // here goes the body of the loop
    }
}
finally
{
    IDisposable disposable = enumerator as System.IDisposable;
    if (disposable != null) disposable.Dispose();
}
```

The behavior you describe points to the cleanup portion of this code. It's possible that the enumerator for the result of the `CssSelectAll` call has a heavy Dispose method. You could confirm this by replacing your loop with something like the code above, and omit the finally block, or set breakpoints to confirm `Dispose` takes forever to run.

Comment: Thanks for this code. It actually hangs on `while (enumerator.MoveNext())` after the 250th table div is found. After the usual 6 mins, we then arrive at the finally block, Disposal happens once, and then I can proceed. ANTS Profiler shows the last call on the stack is `WatiN.Core.Native.InternetExplorer.IEEElement+<>c__DisplayClassc.<WaitUntilElementAvailable>b__b()`

Comment: @MHTri: oh, so it takes a long time to figure out there are no more tds to be found. Unless the document is gigantic (I mean, way too big), I'd report this to the WatiN team as a possible bug. Or it could be something related to IE...

Comment: I've since moved onto trying a different solution, but thank you for trying to help!

Answer (score 3):

You could try this:

```
var eletd = new List<Element>(allMainTDs);
```

Comment: The list constructor will iterate through allMainTDs as well. I don't see how this will help, but it does make the code much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for this shortcut, it has the same effect and time consumption as the foreach loop, but it reads simpler!

Answer (score 1):

If you under .net 4.0 and you execution environment allows for parallelism, you may be should try the

```
  Prallel.ForEach(..);
```

Comment: This sounds neat, but I require the list data before proceeding any further. Thanks for bringing that to my attention though.

Comment: @So then another course of thinking is to look into implementing a custom iterator for the source that generates allMainTDs, you'd have to do your own DOM traversal, but might worth a try.